# how to export my kivy app which has database, kivy file and python file to an exe file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

so, I've been looking for a solution to export my kivy app to an executable file in windows, I tried multiple ways but I encountered errors everytime and failed.
I have a kivy file, python file and a database، can anybody help me and give me a working solution?

I tried using auto-py-to-exe and I read about buildozer and google colab but it seems that they can't build an exe file for windows, they only build apk files for android and ios if I'm not wrong

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try  `pyinstaller`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson hello my friend, I did try it, but I get errors everytime, so I hoped I could find any other solution that suits my case